# How to limit detect object with contour

Tags: python, opencv

To summary i want to detect ball inside field contour

`I tried using pointsPolygonTest but get an error :
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'pointPolygonTest'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - Can't parse 'pt'. Expected sequence length 2, got 60
> - Can't parse 'pt'. Expected sequence length 2, got 60

so how can i detect an object inside some contour?`

```
def contourLapangan(inputCitra, outputCitra):
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(inputCitra, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                  cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

     for cnt in contours:
        if cv.pointPolygonTest(cnt[0], contours, False) > 0:
           cv.drawContours(outputCitra, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 2)


def contourBola (inputCitra, outputCitra):
     contours, _ = cv.findContours(inputCitra, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                   cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

     for cnt in contours:
        (x,y), radius = cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
        center = (int(x), int(y))
        cv.circle(outputCitra, center, int(radius), (255,0,0), 3)
```

Comment: "It will help me if you can please give me some jurnal or link of article for my problem." -- Note that questions asking for off-site resources are off-topic here. [help/on-topic]

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. That includes a proper indentation of your Python code -- right now it's full of syntax errors.

Comment: The second parameter of [`pointPolygonTest`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1a539e8db2135af2566103705d7a5722) should be a single point (a pair of numbers specifying it's coordinates). However, you're feeding it a list of all contours (i.e. a list of lists of points). That won't work.